# Does HL7 V2.X message with multiple OBR segments have same placer order and filler order number?

Tags: medical, hl7-v2

As a part of HL7 parser development, need to know **whether the placer order and filler order number of multiple OBR segments in a HL7 message will be *same***.

Read theory about placer and filler order number in the internet. But was not able to find good examples.

Looking forward for answer with good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a part of HL7 parser development, I personally, would always expect that the placer order and filler order number fields will have different values for each OBR segment in a message. However, I believe it is common for these order numbers to be the same in all OBR segments within a message.

That being said if an ORU (result) message contains observations for a test that is a single specimen with multiple tests performed then you will have multiple OBR and OBX segments for each of the tests performed. In a case such as this the multiple tests could be performed by different laboratories causing different filler order number fields.

Sources:

[Corepoint Health's Website](https://www.corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-obr-segment) OBR definition

Check out the sample message [at this HL7 viewer](https://hl7.cc/farser)

My own 8 years of experience in Healthcare IT.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was very helpful. "multiple tests could be performed by different laboratories" - Denotes that a single HL7 lab results message will contain the results from different test machines. Am I correct? If so can you please provide some examples.